# Lightning Datatable render with new datasource and existing selectedRows after imperative apex call

Tags: lightning-web-components, datatable

I have a use case where i need to render the datatable with the new datasource using imperative apex call and also with the already selected rows but the table is not rendering with the selectedRows..

Datatable HTML:

```
<div if:true={searchData} class="slds-scrollable" style="height:8.5rem;">
                    <lightning-datatable data-id="searchWorkKItem" data={searchData} 
                                            columns={columns} 
                                            key-field="Work_Item_Name__c"
                                            selected-rows={selectedRows}
                                            onrowselection={getSelectedEngagmentName}
                                            class="brandTextlink"
                                            enable-infinite-loading="true"></lightning-datatable>
                </div>
```

Datatable JS:

```
handleSearch() {
        var temp = this.template.querySelectorAll("lightning-datatable")[0];
        if(this.existingValues != null){
            this.productWorkItems = false;
            searchWorkItems({workItemName : this.strSearchWorkItemName,
                        territoryName: this.territoryDefaultAPIValue,
                        losName: this.losDefaultAPIValue})
            .then(result => {
                this.searchData = result;
                this.selectedRows = this.previousSelectedRows;
            })
            .catch(error => {
                this.searchData = undefined;                   
                if(error) {
                    this.errorMsg = error.body.message;
                    this.dispatchEvent(
                        new ShowToastEvent({
                            title: 'No records found!',
                            message: error.body.message,
                            variant: 'info',
                        }),
                    );
                }
            }) 
        }
```

Comment: Please make sure 'this.selectedRows' should have a 'list of key-field values'. Then it will automatically, select the rows.

Comment: @HR Yes..i have tried this.selectedRows with the list of key-field values. But also its not working..whenever i call my apex method, eventhough the selectedRows has values the table is not rendering with selectedRows

Comment: It should work if it has a 'list of key-field values'.
could you please update the question with the complete code?